# Device Reboot Receiver not calling in Android 2.2

Tags: android

I am implementing device reboot receiver in android, I have found in my case it is not executing and I tried to look but could not catch the issue, help me if you can

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationClient.OnAddGeofencesResultListener {

    static final int ONE_MINUTE = 60000;
    Context context;
    LocationClient locationClient;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        this.context = context;
        int resp = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver Reboot", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

<receiver android:name="com.example.BootCompleteReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you are not making the intent apropiate try this....

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 this.context = context;
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);

        int resp = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver Reboot", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

try it an let me know if it works

**EDIT...**

what I do in order to achive what you want is this... I a class that the only thing it does is whait for the Broadcast receiver... When it get the broadcastReceiver create an intent and it lauch the activity that I want to be launch... the code is this...

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

son in my manifest looks like this...

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.app.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

[image]

Comment: and also you need to add the permitions I will add them to the code.. did you add the permitions??

Comment: I have this permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Comment: Ok and do you have an especific class to check for the receiver or are you doing it on the main class???

Comment: A different class for this device reboot receiver

Comment: I had editted my answer try it... of course where says myClass.class is the activity you want to be lauched...

Comment: I simply display the Toast that all

Comment: let my implement it on my code just give me one second

Comment: what if instead of showing a toast you change for a log... do you see the message of Receiver Reboot

Comment: Nothing, I added to start the activity also but not working, onreceive not calling

Comment: I had proved the code you have and it is working totally fine... a sugestion remove the line this.context = context try it and let my know if that helped

Comment: what if you add this line in your manifest  android:enabled="true"

Comment: JAJAJA i'm running out of ideas... do me a favor go to your phone where you are testing the app and please read the permitions of the phone... because when I reboot my phone and the receiver got started I did watch the toast...

Comment: yeh, but not working for me :( This worked when I do this in simple demo project but not in my main application

Answer (score 0):

If it were for a later version (11+), it not being called could be caused by the requirement that the actual application has to have been started at least once before it can receive android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED events.